# Traduction de « sloped backward legs »

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, demande-de-mot

Reviewing a translation.
This is a description of a dancer's body :

> With my long, thin legs that sloped backward and my supersize feet, I had the ideal body for ballet.

Ma version actuelle : Avec mes jambes fines et longues inclinées vers l'arrière et mes pieds de grande taille, j'avais le corps idéal pour le ballet.

J'aimerais trouver mieux pour sloped backward, qui désigne ici  des jambes aux genoux rentrants et à la ligne oblique par rapport au haut du corps.

Answer (score 7):

je propose "galbée" vers l'arrière. Galbé a en effet une connotation positive, harmonieuse, contrairement à, par exemple, arqué ou courbé qui font plutôt penser à une déformation inélégante.

Par ailleurs, je ne sais pas pourquoi mais je trouve que "longues et fines" sonne mieux que "fines et longues".